# Calculate input impedance of this circuit

Tags: capacitor, mosfet

[image]

[image]

I'm not too sure about this. It says neglecting all other capacitances so then surely the Cgs capactior is zero and thus that connection from the gate to between the two caps is relevant. So isn't the input impedance just the series combination of C1 and C2:

$$Z_{in}=\frac{(\frac{1}{jwC_1})(\frac{1}{jwC_2})}{\frac{1}{jwC_1} + \frac{1}{jwC_2}}$$

I feel like I'm missing something very important.

Comment: You are neglecting the effect feedback will have on the current through C2.

Comment: @ThePhoton feedback effect? I'm not too sure, we haven't covered feedback yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an inverting opamp circuit, with enough gain to sustain the GATE voltage changes at near ZERO voltage.

Thus the gate barely moves.

Input capacitance is just the first capacitor.

This assumes the FET is somehow biased ON, with Vdrain sitting near VDD/2 for best signal swing.

Comment: \$ \lambda = 0 \$ suggests that \$ v_{gs} \$ isn't just _near_ zero but exactly zero. \$ \lambda = 1/\left(r_{ds} I_{ds}\right) \$ so if \$ \lambda = 0 \$ then the gain is infinite.

Comment: Hmm. How would it just be the first capacitor? I tried making the small signal model of it but now I have two current sources on the right and a Vx on left